# Proving $\chi_{f^{-1}(A)}(i) =(\chi_{A} \circ f)(i)$

Tags: measure-theory, characteristic-functions

Does this work for any $f$?

\begin{equation}
 \chi_{f^{-1}(A)}(i) =
 \begin{cases}
 1,  & \text{if $i \in f^{-1}(A)$} \\
 0, & \text{if $i \not\in f^{-1}(A)$}
 \end{cases}  =
 \begin{cases}
 1,  & \text{if $f(i) \in A$} \\
 0, & \text{if $f(i) \not\in A$}
 \end{cases}=
 (\chi_{A} \circ f)(i)
 \end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it does.  Hint: learn about Iverson brackets. They're handy for solving these problems.